# Parsing Columns Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I’m trying to parse a column expression for a `DataTable` in `ADO.NET` and identify the set of dependent column names that are contained within it.

Example:

A `DataTable` has 3 columns `Unit Price`, `Quantity` and `BreakEven`.

We could derive two additional columns via column expressions.

```
[Total Sale Value] = “IIF([Unit Price] > 0, [Unit Price] * Quantity, 0)”
[Profit or Loss Indication] = “IIF([Total Sale Value]> BreakEven, ‘Profit’, ‘Loss’)”
```

When I manually parse the column expression for [Total Sale Value], I want to be able to pick up [Unit Price] and “Quantity” as the set of source columns that are contained within it.

Also, when I parse the column expression for `[Profit or Loss Indication]`, I want to be able to pick up [`Total Sale Value`] and “`BreakEven`” as the set of source columns that are contained within it.

From what I can see, even though the .net framework has its own mechanism for parsing column expressions, it does not expose any of that functionality via public classes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be super hacky, you could do something like this:

```
public static class DataColumnExtensions
{
    private static readonly Assembly DataAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DataTable));

    public static bool DependsOn(this DataColumn thisColumn, DataColumn otherColumn)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisColumn.Expression))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var dataExpression = DataAssembly.CreateInstance(
            "System.Data.DataExpression",
            false,
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            new object[] { thisColumn.Table, thisColumn.Expression, thisColumn.DataType },
            null,
            null);

        var dependsOnMethod = dataExpression.GetType().GetMethod("DependsOn", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var result = (bool)dependsOnMethod.Invoke(dataExpression, new object[] { otherColumn });

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's complex - I'd have thought the only way you can do this reliably is by copying the .NET Framework code, i.e. the internal System.Data.DataExpression class, then related classes such as ExpressionNode.